# Duplicated log messages when using configuration file

Tags: python, logging

I'm scratching my head to understand what I made wrong. 
I want to have all application logs configured in one file, so i proceed as follow:

logging.conf

```
[loggers]
keys=root,MONARCH,MONARCH.MESSAGE-PARSER,MONARCH.SYNTAX-PARSER,MONARCH.SYNTAX

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_MONARCH]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=MONARCH

[logger_MONARCH.SYNTAX]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=MONARCH.SYNTAX

[logger_MONARCH.MESSAGE-PARSER]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=MONARCH.MESSAGE-PARSER

[logger_MONARCH.SYNTAX-PARSER]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=MONARCH.SYNTAX-PARSER

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format='%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] - [%(name)s] - %(message)s'
```

A simple call give me duplicated message log:

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("./logging.conf",
                          disable_existing_loggers=True)

l1 = logging.getLogger("MONARCH")
l2 = logging.getLogger("MONARCH.MESSAGE-PARSER")
l3 = logging.getLogger("MONARCH.ME")


l1.info("test l1")
l2.debug("test l2")
l3.info("test l3")
```

Then all messages are duplicated.

```
'2015-06-11 12:09:45,328 - [INFO] - [MONARCH] - test l1'
'2015-06-11 12:09:45,328 - [INFO] - [MONARCH] - test l1'
'2015-06-11 12:09:45,328 - [DEBUG] - [MONARCH.MESSAGE-PARSER] - test l2'
'2015-06-11 12:09:45,328 - [DEBUG] - [MONARCH.MESSAGE-PARSER] - test l2'
'2015-06-11 12:09:45,328 - [DEBUG] - [MONARCH.MESSAGE-PARSER] - test l2'
'2015-06-11 12:09:45,328 - [INFO] - [MONARCH.ME] - test l3'
'2015-06-11 12:09:45,328 - [INFO] - [MONARCH.ME] - test l3'
```

My first goal is to have use [module level log](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial) and have different log level.

Comment: You should only be attaching one root logger which is the highest in the hierarchy

Comment: Sorry but don't really understand.